# Most efficient way to get the data from database

Tags: php, mysql

So what i have is pretty simple.
I have 1 table

**CategorieMain**

*like*

CatMainid

CatMainName

and 1 table:

**CategorieSub**

*like*

CatId

CatName

CatMainId

'

**What i want is :**

A list with all the CatMainName's and under the names all the CatSubNames.

**CatMainId1**

all CatSubNames with CatMainId1

**CatMainId2**

all CatSubNames with CatMainId2

**Etc Etc**

Currently i use php to get the data like

```
 SELECT * from Categoriemain
```

and in the while loop i do

```
 SELECT * FROM CategorieSub WHERE CatMain id = $row['CatMainId']
```

But this is very inefficient because  now if i have 10 CatMainId's i do 10 query's (for each one a while)

**What is the most efficient way to get a list like this, i was thinking about putting it in arrays or something but i couldn't get it working?**

Comment: +1 for realising queries in a while loop is a bad thing `:)`

Comment: You want to learn about "SQL JOIN".  There are bound to be some good tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Use one query:

```
SELECT Categoriemain.*, CategorieSub.CatSubNames FROM Categoriemain
JOIN CategorieSub ON Categoriemain.CatMainid=CategorieSub.Catmainid
```

**Edited,** removed `GROUP BY`

With this query, you don't need the while loop.

I have also added the CatSubNames to the output list of the query fields.

Comment: Okay, removed the `GROUP BY`.  You can also add an `ORDER BY` as shown by @Randy if you want to make more sense of your output.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Categoriemain
JOIN CategorieSub ON Categoriemain.CatMainid=CategorieSub.Catmainid
ORDER BY Categoriemain.CatMainid
```

Comment: Ok but how can i select the right CategorieSub under the CatMainName in the while loop i can get the CatMainNames with  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
     
     echo $row['CatMainName'];
    }

Comment: Have variable where you would store the current main category, then you do a check to see if this category has changed, if it has, you simply create a new Html section or heading, and give the variable the new value, just a suggestion thou, it would be better if this could be done with SQL, any suggestions?

Comment: the suppression of repeating parts of a row can be done with a WINDOW function - but I'm not sure this is available in mysql - it is for sure in Oracle and others.  I think easiest to remove unwanted repeats in the display code as @Hosea Kambonde suggests